# Raspbian router/firewall

Tags: networking, raspbian, ufw

Hello fellow superusers,

Here is the topology of my lan. WAN *-* modem-router-firewall *-* Pi router-firewall *-* lan machines .

I use a test machine in the lan: bob.

I cannot access the internet sites form bob, I get "destination host unreachable".

Here are my routes:

routes on bob (anonymized):

default via *pi-router-iface-inner-lan-eth0* dev eth0 src *bob-ip* metric 202

*inner-lan*/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src *bob-ip* metric 202

*lan-beyond-pi-router (modem + pi-iface-eth1)*/24 via *pi-router-inner-lan-iface-eth0* dev eth0

routes on the pi router:

default via *pi-router-inner-iface-eth0* dev eth0 src *pi-router-inner-iface-eth0* metric 202

default via *pi-router-outer-iface-eth1* dev eth1 src *pi-router-outer-iface-eth1* metric 203

*inner-lan*/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src *pi-router-inner-iface-eth0* metric 202

*lan-beyond-pi-router*/24 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src *pi-router-outer-iface-eth1* metric 203

I use ufw for filters and nat. This is my own idea, not completely sure about it: as I cannot configure a via route on the modem, I enabled NAT on the "external" (eth1) interface of Pi router (interface on the modem side). Here is my ufw config:

'#

'# rules.before

'#

'# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom

'# rules should be added to one of these chains:

'#   ufw-before-input

'#   ufw-before-output

'#   ufw-before-forward

'#

'# nat Table rules

*nat

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT - [0:0]

'# Forward traffic from eth0 through eth1

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

'#personal addition, not sure about it

-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

'# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't be processed

COMMIT

'# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors

*filter

:ufw-before-input - [0:0]

:ufw-before-output - [0:0]

:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]

:ufw-not-local - [0:0]

'# End required lines

'# allow all on loopback

-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT

'# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection

-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

'# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)

-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny

-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

'# ok icmp codes for INPUT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

'# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

'# allow dhcp client to work

-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

'#

'# ufw-not-local

'#

-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

'# if LOCAL, RETURN

-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

'# if MULTICAST, RETURN

-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

'# if BROADCAST, RETURN

-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

'# all other non-local packets are dropped

-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny

-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

'# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above

'# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

'# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above

'# is uncommented)

-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT

---

Now, I can ping the modem from bob, but I cannot access internet properly. Thougb internet DNS works.

When I try to connect to a WAN server I get: "destination host unreachable". I guess I have an issue in my config somewhere, or something is lacking.

Maybe I should configure something on the modem, I don't now. But, no, when I did the tests, I plugged the Pi router on a switch with both ifaces on the same switch at one point I was able to access the net, everything worked. After these tests, I plugged the Pi to its final location, next to the modem. Now, from machine bob to reach WAN, the route goes through a switch, two CPLs, the pi router, the modem.

Thank you very much for your insights :-)

/cr!?ptal

Comment: Your `MASQUERADE` rule applies to traffics from `10.0.0.0/24`, while `bob` is in the subnet of `10.0.x.0/24`, so is `x` `0`? Seriously, stop "anonymizing" private IPs; while they are called "private IPs", it doesn't mean there's any privacy in them. Every household can use them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses

Comment: Also, not sure if you have just been omitting routes on the pi or you simply didn't assign the address on `eth1` with `/24`. You should have a subnet route (`10.0.x.0/24`) for `bob` on it. (Well, or you can just do `/32` with `bob` as its `peer`; but I assume you will hook a switch to eth1 instead someday, so)

Comment: thx for you reply https://superuser.com/users/554702/tom-yan. I have updated the question with new findings :-)

Answer (score 0):

I added a new route on the pi-router and it works!

sudo ip add route default via *modem-router-ip*/24 dev eth1.

and:

sudo su

ufw disable && ufw enable

Moreover, to make this custom route persistent I added it to /etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook .

Mission succeeded :-)